# select value of column doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

I have this php query;

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM store AS s 
        LEFT JOIN setting as set ON (s.store_id = set.store_id)";
$sql .= " WHERE (set.key = 'config_template' OR set.key IS NULL)";    
$sql .= " ORDER BY url";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

What i would like to do is return all rows where `key` is equal to "config_template".  But if there are no keys that match "config_template", I still want to return that row except the column `key` would be empty.

I thought about using `NOT IN` or `NOT EXIST` but I am not sure how to use these in this circumstance?

Comment: i think above query is fine as you have used `set.key IS NULL`. have you try with `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: You said you want a particular `store_id` but you didn't specify that in your query? Also, is it possible to have both `key='config_template'` and `key IS NULL` under the same `store_id` in `setting`? If yes, you would get two rows.

Comment: I have updated the question, i want all the store_ids. There would only ever be key = 'config_template' or it doesnt exist, never both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the condition for the key into the JOIN condition should do the trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM store AS s 
  LEFT JOIN setting as set 
         ON s.store_id = set.store_id AND set.key = 'config_template'
ORDER BY url
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here.

```
$sql .= " WHERE (set.key = 'config_template' OR set.key IS NULL)";
```

In this `where` clause either both condition will be true or false, but it will fail when both condition will be false.

Try this,

```
$sql .= " WHERE (set.key = 'config_template' OR set.key IS NULL) OR/AND SECOND_CONDITION ";
```

In this way you will definitely get result.